# Register client script problem

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to register this simple script, but i can't get this to show the message.
Any idea why my message won't show??
Using asp.net framework 4.0.
Thanks.

```
    String csName = "ChangeDivDir";
    Type csType = this.GetType();

    ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;

    if (!cs.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(csType, csName))
    {
        StringBuilder csText = new StringBuilder();
        csText.Append("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
        csText.Append(" var oDiv = document.getElementById(\"main\"); ");
        csText.Append(" alert('My message'); ");
        csText.Append("<script>");
        cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(csType, csName, csText.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: As a side note, it's usually slower to use a string builder for fewer than ~15-20 string concats

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last line is `<script>`, but it should be `</script>`

Answer (score 3):

Your script tag isn't closed? May be the issue

Answer (score 0):

`</script>` missing in the javascript.add the closing of the script tag and try.

Comment: Your answer doesn't add anything that the other answers have already provided.